# How to remove duplicated code in c# class

Tags: c#, class, refactoring

Please help me to Re-factoring the following code **scenario**

i have two classes

```
class Example1
{
    public string username {private get;set;}
    public string password {private get;set;}
    public  obj[] callfunction(string value) {//code}
}
class Example2
{
    public string UserName {private get;set;}
    public string Password {private get;set;}
    public List<ObjectDefinition> function1(string option) 
    {
        Example1 obj = new Example1();
        obj.username = this.UserName ;
        obj.password = this.Password;
        obj.callfunction(option)
        //Other codes
    }
    public List<ObjectDefinition> function2(string option,string other,string other_more_params) 
    {
        Example1 obj = new Example1();
        obj.username = this.UserName ;
        obj.password = this.Password;
        obj.callfunction(other)
        //Other codes
    }
    public List<ObjectDefinition> function3(string option) 
    {
        Example1 obj = new Example1();
        obj.username = this.UserName ;
        obj.password = this.Password;
        obj.callfunction(option)
        //Other codes
    }
    //so on
}
```

so my question is which is the best way to declare this repeating object declaration.

Comment: This question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: sry, is there any option to move this question

Comment: You can just delete this question and paste it on code review instead. Seems to be in a good format anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a function to create `Example1`

```
class Example2
{
    public string UserName {private get;set;}
    public string Password{private get;set;}
    public List<ObjectDefinition> function1(string option) 
    {
        var example1 = CreateExample1(option);
        example1.callfunction(option); 
        //Other codes
    }
    public List<ObjectDefinition> function2(string option,string other,string other_more_params) 
    {
        var example1 = CreateExample1(option);
        example1.callfunction(option); 
        //Other codes
    }
    public List<ObjectDefinition> function3(string option) 
    {
        var example1 = CreateExample1(option);
        example1.callfunction(option); 
        //Other codes
    }
    //so on

    public Example1 CreateExample1(string option)
    {
        Example1 obj=new Example1();
        obj.username =this.UserName ;
        obj.password=this.Password;
        return obj;     
    }
}
```

Comment: that can't work as it is wrote

Comment: sir the obj.callfunction(option); is different for every function

Comment: not again ... First, you can't call function with a object wich has no existence. Second, you can't return a value in a void function.

Comment: @Xaruth: too early over here, my apologizes and thanks.

Comment: @ClaudioRedi ;) that version can work. Don't know if it answer nikhilsreeni's question, but it works

Comment: thanks this code works

Comment: hi,when i'm doing code analysis in the class Example1,showing this warning:  obj is not disposed along all exception paths. Call System.IDisposable.Dispose on object 'client' before all references to it are out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

How about defining a function that will return an instance of Example1 with the desired username and password:

```
class Example1
{
   public string username {private get;set;}
   public string password{private get;set;}
   public  obj[] callfunction(string value){//code}
}
class Example2
{
   public string UserName {private get;set;}
   public string Password{private get;set;}
   public List<ObjectDefinition> function1(string option) 
   {
    Example1 obj=GetExample1Instance();
    obj.callfunction(option)
    //Other codes
   }
   public List<ObjectDefinition> function2(string option,string other,string other_more_params) 
   {
    Example1 obj=GetExample1Instance();
    obj.callfunction(other)
    //Other codes
   }
   public List<ObjectDefinition> function3(string option) 
   {
    Example1 obj=GetExample1Instance();
    obj.callfunction(option)
    //Other codes
   }

   private Example1 GetExample1Instance()
   {
    return new Example1 { username = this.UserName, password = this.Password }
   }
   //so on
}
```

Or you could consider simply having an instance of Example1 as a member in Example2 (supposing the desired functionality supports this).